# How to determine sample size in unknown population size for regression equation

Tags: regression, sample-size

I want to compute a regression equation for predicting tree volume by independent variable dbh (diameter at breast height) at 95 % confidence interval for 5% error.

What is the formula for sample size if the total population number is unknown?

Comment: It is highly unlikely you would succeed with this as stated: a *prediction* concerns trees not in your sample and thereby is subject to the same amount of variation seen in the population, which is going to exceed 5%. But if you want to *estimate* the *mean* volume for specified dbh values, you can succeed (because the more data you have, the more certain you can be about the mean). The formula necessarily involves an estimate of the residual variation of the error in the regression of log volume against some function of dbh: do you have such information available?